# How to choose table column dynamically?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a data table in which I have month columns(fields).
How do I write a query that would select current month's column dynamically?

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT MonthName(month(date())) FROM my_table
```

That didn't work, so I tried several different ways that would return the month name for a query to use as field name, but so far nothing worked.

Can anybody point me to a solution?

Comment: Normalize your database and everything will go fine. Your design is wrong.

Comment: At this point the only option I see is to use a big a** formula with 12-level deep of IIf(). This is horrible.

Comment: Never though about switch statement! The issue is that the data is sent me in spreadsheet and i am linking Access to that spreadsheet.

Comment: Another option is to build the SQL dynamically and have it create the query that way.  Maybe on Form_Load or something.

Comment: So you have an access table with column names that are full month names and want to write a query to select the column? I just copied your code into Access and made it a `SELECT INTO` statement and the new table looked just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a data source with a column for each month.  You could use `Switch()` to retrieve the values from the column whose name matches the current month.

```sql
SELECT
    Switch
        (
            Month(Date())= 1, [Jan],
            Month(Date())= 2, [Feb],
            Month(Date())= 3, [Mar],
            Month(Date())= 4, [Apr],
            Month(Date())= 5, [May],
            Month(Date())= 6, [Jun],
            Month(Date())= 7, [Jul],
            Month(Date())= 8, [Aug],
            Month(Date())= 9, [Sep],
            Month(Date())=10, [Oct],
            Month(Date())=11, [Nov],
            Month(Date())=12, [Dec]
        ) AS current_month_column
FROM my_table;
```

However, I would try to transform the data source instead, converting columns to rows.

```sql
SELECT 'Jan' AS month_name, [Jan] As month_value FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Feb' AS month_name, [Feb] As month_value FROM my_table
UNION ALL
...
```

You could store the union result set in another table and query that, or query the union query.

```sql
SELECT month_name, month_value
FROM YourTable
WHERE month_name = MonthName(Month(Date()), True);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT " & left(MonthName(Month(Date)), 3) & " INTO new_table FROM my_table"
db.Execute strSQL
```